# Create Alphanumeric ID as per dropdown selected

Tags: php, mysql

I have HTML Form Which contain one drop-down name as Type,containing values like Request, Complaint, Query.
If we select type as a Request then ID in DB should be REQ1, if select Complaint then COMP1, if Query then QUE1 and ID should be increment as per type.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="/action_page.php">
Title:<input type="text">
Type:
<select name="type">
<option value="Request">Request</option>
<option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
<option value="Query">Query</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

In above code We select ticket type from drop-down.Here I want to differentiate ticket by its ID like it is complaint or Request or Query.
If Ticket type is complaint then that ticket ID save as with Prefix COMP, if Query then QUE, if Request then REQ.

Table Look like as follows.

### ID | TITLE

### REQ1 | title1

### REQ2 | Title2

### REQ3 | Title2

### COMP1 | Title3

Comment: No one will presume what you want. So add your code here.

Comment: update your question add   a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: Please See my updated question

Comment: you will display output in  same page or different page like action_page.php

Comment: @Bhargav output will display In different page I.e. in action_page.php. But here main agenda is saving ID in DB with Different prefix depends on Type value.

Comment: question does not show much effort made by OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one will helpfull

**your first file code**

add latest .js file
link:[letest .js library download](https://jquery.com/download/)

**select.php**

```
<form method="post" action="select1.php">
<select name="select">
    <?php
        $select=array(0=>"select",1=>"Request",2=>"Complaint",3=>"Query");
        for($id=0;$id<=3;$id++)
        {
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $select[$id]; ?></option>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="name" id="name">
<input type="submit" name="">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../library/q.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(this).change(function(){
        if($('select').val()!=0)
            $('#name').val($('select :selected').text());
        else
            $('#name').val("");
    });
</script>
```

**your second file code**

**select1.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['select']) && !empty($_POST['select']))
    {
        $id=$_POST['select'];
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $name=strtoUpper(substr($name,0,3));
        echo $name.$id;
    }else
    {
        header("location:select.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your Answer, Please see my edited code where i have added the table structure.

Comment: you have to create table or insert a record

Comment: Insert a record, ID is Alphanumeric.